# Edit Comments Form in TwentyEleven

Tags: comments, theme-twenty-eleven

Is there a way I can edit / change the layout of the comments form (leave a reply form) in the TwentyEleven theme? I want to put the textarea on top and I can change the styles via css but physically moving the forms is where I'm having trouble. I'm not sure where to find the code for it.

tl;dr Where's the comments form code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments template is added to template files via the [`comments_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) template tag.

The `comments_template()` template tag includes the `comments.php` template-part file.

The `comments.php` template-part file includes the comment-reply form via the [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form) template tag. Refer to the Codex (linked) for detailed instructions for modifying the content and output of `comment_form()`.

Comment: I looked at that and it doesn't seem to give me access to just move around the inputs. From the looks of it I would have to create the form from scratch :/

Comment: You have complete control over the form fields, so you can simply re-order them in the fields array.